# How do I turn a dictionary with lists as values into a dictionary with integers as values?

Tags: python, list, sorting, dictionary

I have a dictionary like this:

```
Averages = {'Jennifer': [1],'Chris': [5],'Malcolm': [9]}
```

I want to change and sort that dictionary (not make a new one) into this:

```
Averages = {'Malcolm': 9, 'Chris': 5, 'Jennifer': 1}
```

How would I do this?

Comment: Can you show what you have tried so far?

Comment: Also, are your values always a single item in a list? (when they are in a list)

Comment: You can't sort a dictionary.  You would need to use `collections.OrderedDict`.

Answer (score 1):

Merging both answers together, you should have something like this with an OrderedDict

```
import operator
from collections import OrderedDict

Averages = {'Jennifer': [1],'Chris': [5],'Malcolm': [9]}
Averages ={k:v[0] for k,v in Averages.items()}
Averages = OrderedDict(sorted(Averages.items(),  key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dictionary comprehension`

```
>>> Averages2 ={k:v[0] for k,v in Averages.items()}
>>> Averages2
{'Chris': 5, 'Malcolm': 9, 'Jennifer': 1}
```

Comment: Is this sorted ? I dont think so! and why name the dictionary `Averages2`?

Comment: You almost made it, but it needs to be sorted... Also, answering bad questions merely encourages their continuance.  He has not provided a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example.

Comment: @zondo Yes, I read through the question too fast and I missed the sorting part. My bad. And because I missed the part about sorting the dictionary, at first glance it didn't look like the worst question I had ever seen, but you're right it's a bad question. However, I think my answer might help the OP.

Comment: Thanks guys, this helped I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Dictionaries in python are declared unordered, they don't have order. Because of that you just can't push them to save the order. You can try to create a dict from any ordered object, and it will loose its order, so just forget about that. If you want ordering, use different types, like list or [ordered dict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html).

@Joe К answered you, how to make your dict to be a dict of integers, not lists. If you want to get list of its ordered items, try this:

```
>>>import operator
>>> A = sorted(Averages.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))
>>> A
[('Jenifer', 1), ('Chris', 5), ('Malcolm', 9)]
```

If you think, that this is the order you needed - then good. If you still insist of having those items ordered in dictionary - try it:

```
>>> dict(A)
{'Chris': 5, 'Malcolm': 9, 'Jenifer': 1}
```

It is not possible.